# NotBoundException on localhost

Tags: java, rmi

I have a RMI server running on the localhost, exporting an object of type `Message`:

```java
try {
    MessageServer obj = new MessageServer();
    Message stub = (Message) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 0);
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
    registry.bind("M", stub);
} catch (RemoteException e) {
} catch (AlreadyBoundException e) {
}
```

Then I want to start a client and get the stub for this object. It seems that the registry is found but then in the `try` block a `NotBoundException` is thrown:

> java.rmi.NotBoundException: M
>       at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:136)
>       at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:409)
>       at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
>       at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:377)
>       at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
>       at rmitest.MessageClient.main(MessageClient.java:23)

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
        //String host = "localhost";
        Registry registry;
        Message stub = null;
        try {
            registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            stub = (Message) registry.lookup("M"); //NotBoundException thrown here
        } catch (NotBoundException ex) {
        } catch (AccessException ex) {
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        }
        try {
            stub.insert("TestString"); //NullPointerException here
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        }

}
```

Why is `"M"` not found? Both server and client are started inside Netbeans, the registry is started via terminal beforehand.

Comment: You will never find out until you write some proper exception handling.

Comment: How do you mean that? I catch all possible exceptions and when debugging only the exception with the shown message is thrown at the position marked in the code.

Comment: I mean that the code you posted ignores all exceptions. I include the server code, which has clearly thrown some exception preventing the bind() from executing. If you have other code, post that code, not this code.

Comment: You are right, there indeed was a `RemoteException` on `bind()`.
I thought the debugger jumped to a catch when stepping over a line that throws an exception...
However, using `createRegistry()` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RMI is sort of a beast, it's always an issue how to run it.

First of all, do proper exception handling as @EJP suggested: a reason might be you get a connection timeout or something similar - so put an `e.printStackTrace()` into the `catch` blocks and let's see if we get sort of an error message (btw you gonna stop creating empty `catch` blocks really quickly when you debug a suppressed exception for 2 days). Can't it be your firewall that catches the connection?

I would also change `getRegistry()` to `createRegistry()`, and `bind()` to `rebind()` (it can save you a bit of time).

The exception you're getting is because your main application wasn't able to bind (register) the service you wanted, and it is missing (unavailable) from the default registry.

RMI can be done several ways. The approach you chose is absolutely cool for development and in testing, but you'll need to do some changes if you want to put it under production (e.g., probably there will be a common `rmiregistry` running somewhere, you'll have to use a policy file and some properties like `java.rmi.codebase=...`, you'll need a proper security manager installed, etc.)

Comment: I disagree with your last paragraph. You only need a policy file if you need a security manager, and you only need a security manager for RMI purposes, and java.rmi.server.codebase, if you need the codebase feature, and you don't necessarily need that at all. I usually recommend running the Registry via LocateRegistry.createRegistry(), *especially* if you are using the codebase feature.

Comment: Using `createRegistry()` solved the problem. Why wasn´t I able to use an already running reigstry?

Comment: @user905686 It is completely impossible to answer that definitively without seeing the exception that your code ignores, but most probably it wasn't running at all in the server host.

Comment: @user905686 I believe `getRegistry()` does not start a local registry opposed to `createRegistry()`, which does start an `rmiregistry` service binded to the current Java process (this is great for development, because it is restarted every time you run the program).

Comment: @EJP if you're using `rmiregistry` you do need the codebase and security manager (except the case when `rmiregistry` is started from the current project's package root, so it can find the required classfiles). But indeed, if you're using `createService()` it can see the classes by default.

Comment: @rlegendi Untrue. If you are using `rmiregistry` you need neither the codebase feature nor the security manager. You can place the classes required on the Registry's CLASSPATH.

Comment: @EJP Yes, which is the folder where you started `rmiregistry` :-) If you have classes in a different folder, you'll need them both.

Comment: @rlegendi Wrong again. It doesn't have to have anything to do with the folder from which you started the RMI Registry. It is possible to start it with a classpath argument (or environment variable) that e.g. names JAR files, other directories, whatever you need. I think you need to read my RMI book ;-)

Comment: I'm not an expert of RMI and probably I misunderstand you, but [here's an example](https://github.com/rlegendi/ELTE-javagyak/tree/master/19-rmi/rmitest). Try starting the server with the `server.bat` file, it should work (Win Java 1.7.0_02-b13). Now comment out the `rmiregistry` line, open a new `cmd.exe` e.g. in your home folder, start `rmiregistry` there, and run the script again: the result is a `java.rmi.UnmarshalException: ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: @rlegendi That's not a case of 'start[ing] the RMI Registry with a CLASSPATH argument (or environment variable)'.